# Array index stuck at [0]

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array out of looped data. The variables contain looped data. All works fine, but when array is outputted, the index gets stuck at 0 and doesn't move up from 0 to 1 etc. I wonder what the problem is and how I can get this fixed.

Thanks.

```
$productinfo = array(

     array(   
        "Productname" => "$productname",
        "StarRating" => "$starrating",
        "AddedValue" => "$addedvalue",
        "ProductImage" => "$image",
        "TotalPrice" => "$totalprice",
        "ProductLink" => "$link" )
   );  


$productinfojson= json_encode($productinfo);

$output = json_decode($productinfojson, TRUE);



echo "<pre>";
print_r( $output );
echo "</pre>";
```

The above outputs:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Procuctname] => Pencil Stack
            [StarRating] => 3 
            [AddedValue] => Free Delivery
            [ProductImage] => 
            [TotalPrice] => 5.50
            [ProductLink] => http://---.net/product
        )
)


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Procuctname] => Block Bundle
            [StarRating] => 4 
            [AddedValue] => Free Delivery
            [ProductImage] => 
            [TotalPrice] => 15
            [ProductLink] => http://---.net/product
        )
)
```

UPDATE if only one array is used.

code:

```
$productinfo = array(


            "Productname" => "$productname",
            "StarRating" => "$starrating",
            "AddedValue" => "$addedvalue",
            "ProductImage" => "$image",
            "TotalPrice" => "$totalprice",
            "ProductLink" => "$link" );  

OUTPUT



 Array
    (
                    [Procuctname] => Pencil Stack
                    [StarRating] => 3 
                    [AddedValue] => Free Delivery
                    [ProductImage] => 
                    [TotalPrice] => 5.50
                    [ProductLink] => http://---.net/product
    )



    Array
    (


                    [Procuctname] => Block Bundle
                    [StarRating] => 4 
                    [AddedValue] => Free Delivery
                    [ProductImage] => 
                    [TotalPrice] => 15
                    [ProductLink] => http://---.net/product
    )
```

Comment: Well, you've not really given enough code here.  Where's the loop?  Frankly, from what you've posted, it looks like you're not actually creating a single array but lots of arrays... One in each iteration of the loop, in fact.

Comment: This is exactly what I would expect from the code you have provided. If you were expecting something else then please tell us what you were expecting.

Comment: @symcbean  I want each product group to have its own key, so it's easy to access the data group (name, ratiing, price etc.). Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, loop used is foreach($response->products->product as $product) {

after this variables are set and after that array is created.

Comment: There is only one product in your code, so obviously only item 0 is set. I've deleted my answer, since apparently it doesn't match your expectations. Please try to update your question to make it more clear what you want.

Comment: @GolezTrol, there are 2 products in the loop. As you see 2 different names are returned with different data. 

I have updated the code used without nested array. This will lead to output without indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stems straight from your array creation. There doesn't seem to be a loop anywhere in your code either....

Anyways, lets sort out your array creation. I assume you're getting the data from a database/data source and assigning it to variables, inputting it into an array? Well the way you currently have it, it's overwriting the first index element in the array.

<sup>**Disclaimer:** *The below is pseudo code, until you update with your actual loop code..*</sup>

```
$productinfo = array();
while($row = FETCH_DATA_FROM_SQL()) {
    // assign it to variables here...?
    $productinfo[] = array(
            "Productname" => "$productname",
            "StarRating" => "$starrating",
            "AddedValue" => "$addedvalue",
            "ProductImage" => "$image",
            "TotalPrice" => "$totalprice",
            "ProductLink" => "$link"
       );
}
```

That will add each element to the new `$productinfo` array and you should be able to loop through the elements correctly.

---

One more thing to note, you're decoding your `json` like this:

```
$output = json_decode($productinfojson, TRUE);
```

That second parameter (`TRUE`), turns it into an associative array, not an object. So when you loop it as an object like below:

```
foreach($response->products->product as $product) {...
```

It isn't going to work. If you want it as an object, remove the second parameter (`TRUE`), otherwise loop it as an array:

```
foreach($response['products']['product'] as $product) {...
```